# how to config gulp file with gulp-useref for concatenate html file to js files?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat

i have project structure according below image[image: project structure]:

and i have gulp file for building my projetc , below code is for uglify and minify my scripts :

```
    gulp.task('useref', function(){
            return gulp.src('*.html')
                .pipe(useref())
                .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
                .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

now my question:
my project build successfully but no happening for my html file and concatenate it in to my scripts.min file  , therefor when my project up h can't see any thing!!!!
] astonished what i do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){
        return gulp.src('script/**/*.html')
            .pipe(useref())
            .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
            .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```